# Save output of a SP to a file and create a job to execute it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SP which returns a XML string as output. I want to save the result in a .xml file automatically when the SP is executed. whats the best way to do that?

Comment: i need to setup a job once a day to run the SP, which will save the file to the desired folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be exactly what you are looking for: http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/saving-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-xml-file/

In a nutshell, you have four options:

1. Using CLR Stored Procedure.
2. Using Command Line Utility (OSQL).
3. Using xp_CmdShell utility of SQL Server.
4. Creating OLE objects in SQL Server (sp_OACreate).

I will not paste most of that article here, but it is pretty well written.

Answer (score 1):

**First, saving output to file:**

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from suppliers" queryout "c:\suppliers.txt" -S server -T'
```

**Second, Scheduling a SQL Job**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

**Alternatively (in case of SQL Express)**

- Use command-line SQL to execute the stored procedure from a windows task, scheduled accordingly
- Build a quick .NET application that executes the stored procedure. Then, setup a windows task to run the executable on a schedule.